# Capitalizing the first letter of a word by using CSS to render it in Copperplate Gothic

Tags: html, css

I'm using the 'Copperplate Gothic' typeface in the main menu of my web site. Because of Copperplate Gothic's all-caps nature, I'm using it to capitalize the first letter of each word in some places. How can I use CSS to assign the font-face 'Copperplate Gothic' to the first letter of a word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copperplate Gothic font is bydefault in upparcase and not getting the lower case version of the font.
"Although a true lowercase has never been designed, Copperplate Gothic is ideal for all-capital text typically set in small print"
Reference: http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/family.aspx?FID=40

Comment: Wow, Its amazing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
text-transform:capitalize;
```

You can add css

Comment: I have already try this: style="text-transform: capitalize !important;"

Comment: because Copperplate Gothic make it in upper case.

Comment: Try putting two rules in sequence in your stylesheet:

div.announcement { text-transform: lowercase; }
div.announcement { text-transform: capitalize; }

As the page is being processed, that should cause the div first to be converted to lowercase, and then each word in the div to be capitalized.

Comment: you should use two rules...  first convert everyhting to lowercase and use capitalize

Comment: Capitalize puts everything in lowercase and puts the first character of each word in uppercase, so there's no need to convert to lowercase first. Make sure the font contains the character glyphs you're trying to show.

Comment: @CLuddy Capitalize will not puts everything to lowercase capitalize only make the first letter capital check this  http://jsfiddle.net/aRhuV/

Comment: Apologies, I was sure it did!

Answer (score 0):

you can easily get your desired results through **text-transforn** property.

**CSS**

```
 p.capitalize {text-transform:capitalize;}
```

**HTML**

```
<p class="capitalize">This is some text.This is some textThis is some textThis is some textThis is some textThis is some textThis is some textThis is some textThis is some textThis is some textThis is some textThis is some textThis is some textThis is some textThis is some textThis is some textThis is some textThis is some textThis is some textThis is</p>
```

plese see the demo:- http://jsfiddle.net/dkxUX/18/

Comment: I have already try this: style="text-transform: capitalize !important;" because Copperplate Gothic make it in upper case.

Comment: @khawarPK i have checked it on net your font is in already by-default in uppercase but i have downloaded from this site: -http://www.font-zone.com/download.php?fid=2967

Comment: how i can use this font on my running site? we just need single item of menu in capitalize text.

Comment: hey i actually when i downloaded your same font from this its in lowercase so you can convert into capitalized case via text-transform property i have used on my system its working hope will work on your end as well .....

Comment: Shailender Arora:Thanks, Let me check

Comment: do you need all the characters to be in capital letter or first letter  ? because i am trying on your live site its creating problems because default font is in uppercase.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12902/discussion-between-shailender-arora-and-khawarpk)

Comment: i need first letter capital in only single item of menu, remaining will be same as it is

Answer (score 0):

Hey now used this

```
{
text-transform: capitalize !important;
}
```

Comment: I have already try this: style="text-transform: capitalize !important;" – khawarPK 1 min ago edit 
because Copperplate Gothic make it in upper case.